# FQL - stream limit

Tags: post, stream, facebook-fql, limit

I'm trying to execute the following FQL query:

```
SELECT post_id,type,created_time,message,like_info,comment_info,share_count,actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=... AND created_time > ... AND created_time < ... LIMIT 1000
```

Every time I execute the query on different source_id, the number of rows returned is lower than 500.
I know that FB gets all the results and then removes results not visible to the viewer. Do you know if there is a default limit (maybe 500) for the query to the stream table?
Thanks in advance